# is it possible to copy the xcode project from one mac to another mac?

Tags: xcode, macos

I am developing iphone application, using xcode 4.2 now I have installed mac in another computer , in that computer i have installed xcode 4.3.3. now I need to move or copy the developed xcode application from my xcode 4.2 mac computer to xcode 4.3.3 mac computer. is it possible to do that?

I did below two steps:

1. compress and send a mail from xcode 4.2 mac computer and download that from xcode 4.3.3 mac computer.
2. And I just copy the project to pen drive and paste into another computer.

Is it any other way to copy or move from one mac computer to another computer? Please guide me, I am trying this past one week.

Comment: Did you consider git as a solution?  You know, so you can go backwards in time to fix customer issues?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this, but there a few things to consider.  Firstly, please, please, please use Source Control. If you want something simple that Xcode has built-in support for then use [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) which is easy to set up. If you want something more powerful (which I suspect you won't just yet) then there's Git.  Once you've set up version control then you don't need to copy or email anything -- you just 'commit' a change from one machine to the repository and then on the other machine you 'check out' the source. If you make any changes on the other machine then you can check that in too and then 'update' on the first machine to receive that change.

As for Xcode, you can use the same project file on another machine and even with a different version of Xcode. You have to ensure though that the paths to files in the project are relative and not absolute.  If the paths are absolute then this means it's less likely it'll build on the other machine unless the paths are identical.  Newer versions of Xcode are much better about having this as the default behaviour.

If there are any files that have absolute paths you can change it by selecting the file in the Project Navigator and then showing the Utilities panel at the right. In the 'Identity and Type' group there's a Location setting where you can set it to be absolute or relative.